# Using cities of the same name as nodes (NetworkX)

Tags: list, python-3.x, networkx

I recently ran into a problem with NetworkX.  I am trying to build a graph of cities from a file.  Some city names are the same but are located in different states. Because of this I am losing cities when I try to call different methods. I know that I can append an element multiple times to a list if I know how many times I want it there. Is there a way I can append multiple elements to a list without actually knowing the number of times it will append???

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you give some example code? Look at [mcve]

Comment: Refer [How To Ask On Stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and Take a Tour

Comment: The nodes labels in a `network` graph are distinct. You can't duplicate labels. Include the state as part of the label or find another method.

Comment: @aryamccarthy , thank you. that is all I needed to know.  Sorry everyone I felt like this was a straight forward question and Aryan answered it.

Comment: This question didn't need any more information than what was provided--it's perfectly clear what the problem is from the above.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I wrap things in a class to deal with this:

```
class CityNode:
    group_count = 0
    def __init__(self, city_name):
        self.city_name = city_name
        self.group_number = copy.deepcopy(CityName.group_count)
        CityNode.group_count += 1
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}({})".format(self.city_name, self.group_number)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "CityNode({})".format(self.city_name)
```

I know this isn't ideal but this is what I've done in some projects. This way when storing in the graph you get distinct nodes for cities with the same name.

Alternatively create a `CityNode` with the state as a parameter that gets stored in the Networkx node.